# Multiple javascript functions on an index page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to update some existing javascript code in place that navigates the user to a desktop depending on whether their device has Flash or not. However, I now want the option to navigate the user to a Mobile site if the screen width is smaller that 800px.

I have included the code below which is not working and I think I have the characters wrong between the two function requirements. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 800) {
window.location = "mobile.htm";
}
if ((navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" &&
navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") == -1 && 
navigator.appVersion.indexOf("3.1") == -1) ||
(navigator.plugins && navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"])
                   || navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash 2.0"]){
window.location='home_f.htm';
}
else {
window.location='home_n.htm';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check the error log?

Comment: When you say it "is not working", what is it doing? Is the browser navigating to home_f.htm instead of mobile.htm on a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that the code above (with the screen.width and all) is executing properly, but then, while mobile.htm is still loading, the code continues. Because you have Flash, the code below it still executes and before mobile.htm can fully load the browser instead decides to obey the later if statement and go to home_f.htm .

Try creating a function that returns after the first bit, like so:

```
function redirect() {
if (screen.width <= 800) {
window.location = "mobile.htm";
return;
}
if ((navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" &&
navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") == -1 && 
navigator.appVersion.indexOf("3.1") == -1) ||
(navigator.plugins && navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"])
                   || navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash 2.0"]){
window.location='home_f.htm';
}
else {
window.location='home_n.htm';
}
}
redirect();
```

I'd also like to note that screen.width measures the screen resolution, but if the browser is resized, it will not take into account the browser's new size. It'll take the size of the entire monitor regardless of the size of the browser. If that isn't what you want, read up on measuring the browser width and height here: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow

Finally, for what you're doing, that is, detecting mobile devices, you may prefer browser detection to basing it off the screen size. There is a simple way to detect if your user is using Android via a user agent. In your case scenario feature detection is probably not applicable. But do remember to provide a link to the mobile version of the site from your non-mobile version just in case of false positives! You never know.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android")!=-1||navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("googletv")!=-1||navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("htc_flyer")!=-1) {
// this person is using Android. Redirect the the mobile site!
window.location = "mobile.htm";
return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adam and Lee for feeding back, and thank you to tomysshadow for providing a solution that worked. First post and it was a success so inclined to use to more frequently to learn.